# PineScript - Monthly / Weekly Volume on Daily timeframe

Tags: pine-script

Is there an easy way to reference volume on a different time frame?

For example if i'm on the daily time frame, but I want my indicator to reference the weekly volume (not the cumulative volume from the past 5 days)?

Comment: Nevermind... got it!

Answer (score 1):

To have more flexiblility you could use inputs for the desired timeframe and symbol, like so...

```
res = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="W")
sym = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval="EURUSD")
vol = security(sym, res, volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", volume)